# Android SocketTimeoutException after idle / sleep

Tags: java, android, timeout, httpurlconnection, socket-timeout-exception

I'm having an issue with my app sending http requests to my server. It automatically sends updates to the server via a service every minute, but after it's been idle for some time, it occasionally loses all connectivity to the server and all subsequent requests time out. I have a ping function in the app that sends a single request on demand, and that also times out.

I have 4 devices running the app right now and only 1 of them is showing this issue. Like I said, it only happens occasionally. I can sometimes leave the device running for several hours with no issues.

Also, I've tried running other apps on the device and they connect just fine.

The device that's causing problems is a Motorolla TC55, running Android 4.1.2

```
 public static JSONObject sendRequest( String unsignedURL, JSONObject request,
  String transactionUUID ) throws Exception {

request.put( "url", unsignedURL );
request.put( "accessKeyId", ACCESS_KEY );
request.put( "signatureMethod", "HmacSHA256" );
request.put( "protocol", "1.0" );
request.put( "timestamp",
    ConnectProtocol.getIso8601DateTimeFormat( ).format( new Date( ) ) );
request.put( "transactionUUID", transactionUUID );
String reqData = request.toString( );

byte[] reqDataBytes = reqData.getBytes( "UTF-8" );
String asciiReqData = new String( reqDataBytes, "ASCII" );
String signature = ConnectProtocol.calculateRFC2104HMAC( "HmacSHA256",
    asciiReqData, ACCESS_KEY );
String signedURL = unsignedURL + "?signature="
    + URLEncoder.encode( signature, "UTF-8" );
URL url = new URL( signedURL );

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection( );

connection.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length",
    Integer.toString( reqDataBytes.length ) );

connection.setUseCaches( false );
connection.setDoInput( true );
connection.setDoOutput( true );

connection.setConnectTimeout( CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS );

DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream( ) );
wr.write( reqDataBytes );
wr.flush( );
wr.close( );

if ( connection.getResponseCode( ) != 200 ) {
  return null;
}

InputStream is = connection.getInputStream( );
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( is ) );

String line;
StringBuffer responseBuf = new StringBuffer( );
while ( (line = rd.readLine( )) != null ) {
  responseBuf.append( line );
  responseBuf.append( '\r' );
}
rd.close( );
connection.disconnect( );

return new JSONObject( responseBuf.toString( ) );
```

}

Also, my server logs any requests and I'm not seeing anything from that device, but am seeing messages from the other devices connected to it.

I've searched for answers but can't find anything related to my issue in particular.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're leaking if the response code wasn't 200. Close the input stream, and disconnect the HttpURLConnection.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for the reply. I just tried this to no avail. I close the connection before returning, but it still times out.

Comment: I am facing same king of issue. Did you find any solution or even the cause of this issue?